# Spark SQL - Concatenate two Dataframes in SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Dataframes with only one record and one column each and i want to concatenate them to retrieve the result in one single row.

Currently: (two separated dataframes)

```
+-----------+
|women color|
+-----------+
|         14|
+-----------+

+---------+
|men color|
+---------+
|       11|
+---------+
```

Desired:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
|women color|men color|women-men   |
+-----------+---------+------------+
|         14|       11|           3|
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the `women-men` column come from?

Comment: subtraction - women minus men

Answer (score 0):

you can crossjoin the two dataframes if they have only 1 row each:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(14).toDF("women color")
val df2 = Seq(11).toDF("men color")

df1.crossJoin(df2)
  .withColumn("women - men", $"women color" - $"men color")
  .show()

+-----------+---------+-----------+
|women color|men color|women - men|
+-----------+---------+-----------+
|         14|       11|          3|
+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Or even better: don't use spark dataframes for this task, just use plain scala datastructures